Unable to write the output values to an xlsx file using python script
Unable to write the output values to an xlsx file using python script. The output obtained after the calculation say for x,y able to write only last result.
The output obtained after the calculation say for x,y should able to write in xlsx sheet for each file from the provided folder.Expected result as below:


Show us your code, don't be shy :)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
